# App ignores input after the Scanner.nextLine() method

Tags: java, string, input, java.util.scanner, string-comparison

I'm new to java and I decided to write a simple program to practice IFs. Here's what it should do:

1. Ask the user about the currency.
2. Ask the user about the amount of money he wants to transfer.
3. Calculate the commission rate and show the details to the user.
4. Ask the user for confirmation; if he types "y" , the program should print "A". If he types "n" , the program should print "B".

Here's the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommissionRate {

static String Confirm;
static byte CommissionRate=10;
static String Commission="1%.";
static double TotalCost;
static double MoneyAmount;
static byte CurrencyNum;
static char CurrencySign;
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void Currency(){

    System.out.println("Please choose your desired currnecy.");
    System.out.println("1.USD");
    System.out.println("2.EUR");
    System.out.println("3.GBP");
    System.out.println("4.CAD");
    System.out.println("5.CNY");
    System.out.println("6.JPY");
    CurrencyNum = sc.nextByte();
    if (CurrencyNum==1|CurrencyNum==4) {

        CurrencySign= '$';
    }
    else {

        if (CurrencyNum==2){

            CurrencySign='€';
        }
        else {
            if (CurrencyNum==3){

                CurrencySign='£';
            }
            else {
                if (CurrencyNum==5|CurrencyNum==6){

                    CurrencySign='¥';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void MoneyAmount() {

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money you would like to transfer :");
    MoneyAmount = sc.nextDouble();
    if (MoneyAmount>499 & MoneyAmount<10000){
        CommissionRate=5;
        Commission="0.5%.";
    }
    else{
        if (MoneyAmount>10000){
            CommissionRate= 3;
            Commission="0.3%.";
        }
    }
    TotalCost = MoneyAmount + MoneyAmount * CommissionRate/1000;
    System.out.println("Please confirm the transfer. ( y/n ) ");
    System.out.println("A transfer of "+MoneyAmount+CurrencySign+".");
    System.out.println("Commission rate is "+Commission);
    System.out.println("You need to pay " + TotalCost+"." );
    sc.nextLine();
    Confirm = sc.nextLine();
    if (Confirm=="y"){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    else if (Confirm=="n") {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
}
```

At first , the program wouldn't wait for the user to confirm/abort the transfer and it would print "B". Then , I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955028/code-doesnt-wait-for-user-input) and  added the "sc.nextLine()". However the program just ignores the last if and doesn't print anything. Any ideas on what causes the problem and how to solve it ?

p.s.: Here's what I get when running the program:

```
Please choose your desired currnecy.
1.USD
2.EUR
3.GBP
4.CAD
5.CNY
6.JPY
2   // my input
Please enter the amount of money you would like to transfer :
120  // my input
Please confirm the transfer. ( y/n ) 
A transfer of 120.0€.
Commission rate is 1%.
You need to pay 121.2.
y  // my input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try

```
if (Confirm.equals("y")){
```

and

```
else if (Confirm.equals("n"))
```

with `==` you compare the object references not the values.

Answer (score 1):

Try `equals` instead of `==`  and one times should be `sc.nextLine();`

```
Confirm = sc.nextLine();
if (Confirm.equals("y")){
```

instead of

```
 sc.nextLine();
    Confirm = sc.nextLine();
    if (Confirm=="y"){
```